# HTML email problems in Hotmail

Tags: html, css

I made an HTML email which is displayed perfectly fine in Gmail, but with some strange hotmail errors. I have the following html

```
<?php
[..]

$mailTxt = "<div style=\"font:11pt/22pt Arial;color:black;width:100%;background:black;text-align:justify;\">
    <div style=\"height:150px;background:black;display:table;\">
        <div style=\"display:table-cell;width:160px;vertical-align:top;\">
            <img src=\""._BASE_URL."/inc/images/SingleDays-Mailing-Logo.jpg\" style=\"margin:25px;\">
        </div>
        <div style=\"display:table-cell;vertical-align:top;\">
            <h1 style=\"font:19pt/22pt Arial;letter-spacing:-0.5pt;color:#cc2439;padding-top:40px;\">SingleDays Nieuwsbrief, ".$_POST['date']."</h1>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div style=\"background:white;margin:0 25px;padding:25px 10%;border-bottom:solid 1px #eee;\">
        <h2 style=\"font:17pt/22pt Arial;letter-spacing:-0.5pt;color:#cc2439;text-transform:uppercase;\">".$_POST['s1']."</h2>
        <p style=\"text-align:justify;\">".$_POST['t1']."</p>
    </div>
    <div style=\"display:table;background:white;margin:0 25px;border-bottom:solid 1px #eee;\">
        <div style=\"display:table-cell;padding:25px;border-right:solid 1px #eee;width:50%;\">
            <h2 style=\"font:15pt/22pt Arial;letter-spacing:-0.5pt;color:#cc2439;\">".$_POST['s2']."</h2>
            <p style=\"text-align:justify;\">".$_POST['t2']."</p>
        </div>
        <div style=\"display:table-cell;padding:25px;width:50%;\">
            <h2 style=\"font:15pt/22pt Arial;letter-spacing:-0.5pt;color:#cc2439;\">".$_POST['s3']."</h2>
            <p style=\"text-align:justify;\">".$_POST['t3']."</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div style=\"display:table;background:white;margin:0 25px;\">
        <div style=\"display:table-cell;padding:25px;border-right:solid 1px #eee;width:50%;\">
            <h2 style=\"font:15pt/22pt Arial;letter-spacing:-0.5pt;color:#cc2439;\">".$_POST['s4']."
            <p style=\"text-align:justify;\">".$_POST['t4']."</p>
        </div>
        <div style=\"display:table-cell;padding:25px;width:50%;\">
            <h2 style=\"font:15pt/22pt Arial;letter-spacing:-0.5pt;color:#cc2439;\">".$_POST['s5']."</h2>
            <p style=\"text-align:justify;\">".$_POST['t5']."</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div style=\"background:black;color:white;\">
        <p style=\"margin-left:25px;\">Je ontvangt deze nieuwsbrief omdat je aangegeven hebt deze te willen ontvangen. Via <a href=\""._BASE_URL."/unsubscribe/".md5($receivers[$i])."\" style=\"text-decoration:underline;color:#cc2439;\">deze link</a> kun je je weer uitschrijven.
    </div>
</div>";

[..]
?>
```

This works perfectly fine in Gmail, but the problems occur in Hotmail (and since i'm working on an Apple without Office i can't even check outlook..)

First of all, all my headings turn out green. I already tried an `color:#cc2439 !important;` but without any result, still green

Besides that are the margins handled incorrectly (which [should](http://www.campaignmonitor.com/css/) be supported)

Problems seem pretty basic to me, so i was wondering if someone knows an easy solution I don't have any clue how to solve the color issue.

**EDIT:**

Solved the color issue by replacing the heading elements with a paragraph. Apparently Hotmail's stylesheet overrules user styled headers

Comment: Give us an example of the generated HTML, not some PHP code - that's not what Hotmail is seeing, so why should we.

Comment: If you are not testing Outlook, Hotmail is the least of your troubles.

Comment: @KristianAntonsen Makes sence. Checked it though and it looks the same!

Comment: @ScottSimpson i already am afraid of that...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few tips:

1 - Campaign monitor has a good guide on what's supported on different mail clients.
http://www.campaignmonitor.com/css/

2 - Exact Target (you have to pay) has an excellent service where it automatically tests your email on a variety of clients and makes screen-shots of them all, which you can view online or download as PDF.
http://www.exacttarget.com/

Comment: Second link might be interesting! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Try taking a look at the source of the message as Hotmail renders it - it may be messing with your tags, and you should be able to find out why there.

Secondly, I'd use Chrome's Inspect Element feature to inspect the items within the email - your styles may be applying properly, but some *other* item is overriding your styles.  (Firebug in Firefox and Developer Tools in Safari also all do this, I just don't know the exact terms for them.)