# Laravel4: how to style an email

Tags: email, laravel, laravel-4

I an a newsletter app, i send a view as a template of mail.
Inside the view there a variable that hold the content taken from a form.
I try to apply different inline style to the view, but no one worked.
This is the view, now there is only one style (color:blue) to test css:

```
<html>
<body style="color:blue;">

   {{ $content }}

</body>
</html>
```

How can i do to style this view, and send a mail with the proper css style?
Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do styling like this,

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
  <p style="font-style:italic">
    {{ $content }}
  </p>
</body>
</html>
```

It works for me.

Comment: More problem here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19032836/yahoo-mail-not-showing-correct-font-family

Comment: What you suggest for Hotmail, there is no way at all to style?

Comment: Check this post for hotmail - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8841458/html-email-problems-in-hotmail  and http://www.campaignmonitor.com/blog/post/3228/a-fix-to-background-color-and-alignment-issues-in-windows-live-hotmail/