# Yahoo mail not showing correct font family

Tags: html, css, email

I have just completed my HTML email, it is working fine on Gmail, Outlook 2010 however when I opened it on Yahoo email it show Times New Roman instead of Verdana font I have used in my email.

Also inspected the reason and found Yahoo adds a `<p>` tag before each text and apply a id on it. which has CSS style

```
#yiv7369716753 p {
    font-family: "Times New Roman","serif";
    font-size: 12pt;
}
```

I have also tried to override this by using CSS block and also used inline styles on  but no success...

```
body, p, #yiv9010530589 p {
    margin:0; 
    padding:0; 
    font-family:"Verdana", Geneva, sans-serif!important;
}
```

Anyone if you have any solution then please share the same, because I have tried to search it online but not get something prominent instead of suggestions like use inline styles and use important within styles.

Comment: Can you show us a sample of your HTML? It will help.

Comment: You really need to use inline styles since they cannot easily be overridden. "!important" is a blunt instrument that should be avoided.

Comment: You should use inline styles, and put your styles in your TD elements. If you need more than one style in the same TD, try nesting those elements into a new table with separate rows and TDs. Use spans if you need to style single words of groups of words within a sentence... Inline. All of that.

Comment: if you use important then you need to have a space between the rule and !important

Answer (score 3):

I've had this problem with Yahoo many many times, and google how to fix it every time, without fail. The only thing I've found that works is removing all quotation marks (single and double) from the font family declaration.

```
font-family:"Verdana", Geneva, sans-serif!important;
```

becomes....

```
font-family:Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;
```

and that should work. Obviously this may have other consequences for two-word fonts, but that's another problem for another day.

Answer (score 1):

Use a style block in your header to override Yahoo's paragraph style:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
        <title>Insert Title</title>
        <style>
            p {
                font-family: Arial, sans-serif !important;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
```

Answer (score 0):

Make e-mail template always a problem, each e-mail program works different from each other so i suggest to you use a boilarplate template, why ? because alot of the common problems are already solved, a really good example is http://htmlemailboilerplate.com/ but if you search on google you will find much more...